# Animate text content of div with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

is anyone know how can I animate content of div with JQuery function animate()? Animate on whole div is simply, but I need have div on default position and animate only his text content (SlideUp or FadeIn effect isn´t relevant).
I used it in nivo slider to show for each image div with his title div is still on same position but content is change to title of new image and I need

1. show div
2. show content (title) with some effect.

This is general question for JQuery, apply this to nivo slider is same as apply in another situations and for that I don´t use tag for Nivo slider.
Before someone written "Use new div included in div for title where you add image title and animate this new div." then I mean this isn´t good solution because I must change script and this create new useless div.

> nivoCaption.html(title);

"nivoCaption" is div container ; "title" is title variable where I have actual title of actual image and I need animate only title not whole nivoCaption (I try - nivoCaption.html(title).animate({right: "100px",}, 750); but this test animate whole conteiner)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

you can put the text in a span, then use its selector in jQuery. eg:

```
<div>
  <span id="mySpan">some text</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mySpan").fadeTo(0,0);
  $("#mySpan").fadeTo("slow",1);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/wy4wd/

enjoy! :)

Comment: This is same as I add title to div and about it I wrote on top. :) I still tried this solution but I search for solution where I don´t need create special div/span only for title.

Comment: You could still use `nivoCaption.html(title);` and instead of setting **title** to `i am a title`, you could set it to `<span id="mySpan">i am a title</span>` and then use `$("#mySpan").fadeTo("slow",1);` :)

Comment: If you still have trouble, i wouldn't mind installing this plugin to find your solution :). If it does work, congrats, and feel free to mark this question as answered.

Comment: I still test it if this is solution then I upvote your answer no fear.

Comment: When I use this solution then my example work same as worked => adding span is ok but his animate is ignore. I mean I must add span to another position in code as in my old solution that probably works but this is not ideal (create new CSS style etc. ...) and still I need change in nivo slider script.

Comment: [working example here](http://www.teachmeinplainenglish.com/so/demo/). add an id to each `<img/>`, then use `$("#yourSlideID").attr("title","your new caption");` in jQuery to change a caption instead of `nivoCaption.html(title);`. enjoy :)

Comment: Change caption when slideshow show new image is simply this work me but I need effect when new slide arrived than show black div and after that fadeIn (for example) his title. In your example is 1 image and for that I not see if effect work.

Comment: I mean this probably work. For "kick me" to solution with special span I add you upvote. Although I made some changes against your answer (span I add to div not to title and some small things in js file). Thanks for help with my problem.

Comment: hi. just updated the link and got the fade + caption change to work. the javascript+jQuery is a little complex, so i will add some comments in the next 2 minutes. enjoy :)

Comment: I look at it. Good night, I have lunch. :)

Comment: Right now is code ok maybe later I must update him, but now is everything ok. Thanks once more.